# Amending sum_range in nested INDIRECT returns #Value error (SUMPRODUCT/SUMIFS)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

**Original, working formula**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&INVOICE&"'!"&"H48"), INDIRECT("'"&INVOICE&"'!"&"G11"),">="&C19,INDIRECT("'"&INVOICE&"'!"&"G11"),"<="EOMONTH(C19,0)))
```

Breakdown:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    SUMIFS(
        INDIRECT("'"&INVOICE&"'!"&"H48"),
        INDIRECT("'"&INVOICE&"'!"&"G11"),
        ">="&C19,INDIRECT("'"&INVOICE&"'!"&"G11"),
        "<="EOMONTH(C19,0)
    )
)
```

This above formula works pretty well to sum up all the amount (`H48`), I enter a month in `C19`, and sum is done against the invoice list of that month.

---

**Formula which returns #Value Error**

Currently having a problem where this Excel formula below returns a `#Value!` error

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&INVOICE&"'!"&"H19:H46"), INDIRECT("'"&INVOICE&"'!"&"G11"),">="&C19,INDIRECT("'"&INVOICE&"'!"&"G11"),"<="EOMONTH(C19,0)))
```

Breadown:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    SUMIFS(
        INDIRECT("'"&INVOICE&"'!"&"H19:H46"),   <== H48 replaced by H19:H46          
        INDIRECT("'"&INVOICE&"'!"&"G11"),
        ">="&C19,INDIRECT("'"&INVOICE&"'!"&"G11"),
        "<="EOMONTH(C19,0)
    )
)
```

The only thing changed is the `sum_range` (`H19:H46`) which is the same total amount of value in `H48`.

Can anyone explain the `#Value!` in that 2nd formula and any solutions to it?
Any help is much appreciated :))

Comment: What would the formulas look like without the Indirect? Can you create them with real ranges? Also, step through the formula with the Evaluate Formula tool on the Formulas ribbon to see where the Value error occurs.

Comment: Added relevant tags. Amended title. Formatted code so that it is more readable, and highlighted the difference between the working and non-working version.
Unclear secondary question removed.

Comment: Thanks for the correction gms0oulman :D
That looked far more better than before

Comment: ok teylyn, will try out
Thanks for the suggestion. Appreciated :))

Comment: i tried to analyse the formula and played around it but still cant get any answers to it. However, the formula without the indirect formula inside was doing greatly

Comment: i was going to extract the amount of 'something' sold when i insert a particular date from invoices of that date

Comment: any possible alternative solutions to that?

Answer (score 0):

This formula you can use multiple criteria, multiple sheet, with month-wise:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&powerpp&"'!v2:v500"),INDIRECT("'"&powerpp&"'!$D$2:d500"),$D30,INDIRECT("'"&powerpp&"'!$e$2:e500"),$H$3,INDIRECT("'"&powerpp&"'!$c$2:c500"),">="&$P$25,INDIRECT("'"&powerpp&"'!$c$2:c500"),"<=" &EOMONTH($P$25,0)))
```